# Service Cloud for Slack - create private channel fails

Tags: servicecloud, slack

In our Service Cloud for Slack setup, when a user (customer support agent) tries to start a swarm in a new Private slack channel in our workspace, the following error ensues:

```
This error occurred when the slackCreateChannel action tried to execute
the Slack API method: conversations.create. Error: restricted_action.
```

The Service Cloud for Slack bot (app) has `permission groups:write` and states
`Manage private channels that Service Cloud for Slack has been added to and create new ones`

However, our Slack Workspace is configured to allow private channels only to be created by workspace `owners/admins`. Needless to say, our service agents aren't Slack workspace owner/admins.

- SFDC Support said we needed to open up Slack private channel creation to anyone - but we can't do this for policy reasons.
- Slack support was asked if there was a way to assign the bot as a workspace owner/admin and the answer we got was:

> Yes, we have seen this issue come up before. Yes, we've seen that the 'Service Cloud for Slack' app feature of creating a private or public slack channel works when the permission to create channels isn't restricted to only Owners/Admins.
>
> For your setup, the 'Service Cloud for Slack' app needs to be allow you to select a specific Owner/Admin account for creating the channel.
>
> However, since the 'Service Cloud for Slack' app was actually created directly by the Salesforce team, you'll need to create a support case directly with them to see if they can take that suggestion into consideration.

This feels like *getting the runaround*.  Has anyone figured out a way for the SFDC Swarm user to create private Slack channels when the Slack workspace is configured to only allow Owners/Admins to create private channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per SFDC Support (and confirmed by us), the only workaround without writing a Slack app to listen for private channel creation events coming from the `Service Cloud for Slack` bot and then auto-converting them to private is to do the following:

- Pre-create by the Slack workspace admin/owner 1..n private channels

  - Assign as channel members any of the SFDC users/Slack users allowed to select those channels for initiating a swarm.
  - Assign the bot `Service Cloud for Slack` to the channel(s)

When the SFDC user opts to use an existing channel, they can select the private channel.

- A pinned swarm thread is created within that channel.
- Replies within that Slack thread go back to the SFDC case's Slack LWC component (and vice-versa)

If two SFDC cases share the same Slack channel, then each gets their own thread within that channel.   Slack messages posted (in Slack) outside of the swarm threads will not be posted to any SFDC Case's Slack LWC component